# org.graphstream.ui.layout.LayoutRunner run INFO: Layout 'SpringBox' process stopped. Is it a problem?

Tags: java, javafx, graphstream

I use GraphStream in my application and to show graphs I use a FXViewer for every graph.
Initially I want to show the different graphs, without setting positions of nodes, so I use the enableAutoLayout() method:

```
 ArrayList<FxViewer> viewers = new ArrayList<>();
 foreach(Graph graph : graphList) {
 FxViewer viewer = new FxViewer(graph, FxViewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_GUI_THREAD);
 viewer.addView(graph.getId(), new FxGraphRenderer());
 viewer.enableAutoLayout();
 viewers.add(viewer);
 }
```

Next, I want to show the same graphs but with fixed positions setted manually and so, for every graph, I disable the autoLayout to the related FXViewer.

```
viewers.forEach(Viewer::disableAutoLayout);
```

But, for every time I disable the autoLayout to a FXViewer in my console appears this message:

```
org.graphstream.ui.layout.LayoutRunner run
INFO: Layout 'SpringBox' process stopped.
```

Is it a problem? Should I do something or I can just ignore this message?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra i asked only if it is a problem that type of message........

Comment: Graph stream provide you with info on how to get help; “You may also share your questions on the mailing list at http://sympa.litislab.fr/sympa/subscribe/graphstream-users“ from their website https://github.com/graphstream/gs-ui-javafx section titled “Help”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might have the same question, here is the answer from the team of GraphStream:

> That message is emitted by the LayoutRunner that handles the graph layout in a different thread. That thread is stopped when you disable the auto layout. And as the log category says, it's just info, so nothing to worry about.